# Initial authorization issue in mysql

Tags: mysql

I tried multiple ways to install mySql and then access the database on a fresh installation. OS is RHEL 7. package used is mysql-5.7.7-0.3.rc.el7.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar

```
installation process: 
[root@host1 mysql]# rpm -ivh mysql-community-common-5.7.7-0.3.rc.el7.x86_64.rpm mysql-community-libs-5.7.7-0.3.rc.el7.x86_64.rpm mysql-community-client-5.7.7-0.3.rc.el7.x86_64.rpm mysql-community-server-5.7.7-0.3.rc.el7.x86_64.rpm
 Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
 Updating / installing...
1:mysql-community-common-5.7.7-0.3.################################# [ 25%]
2:mysql-community-libs-5.7.7-0.3.rc################################# [ 50%]
3:mysql-community-client-5.7.7-0.3.################################# [ 75%]
4:mysql-community-server-5.7.7-0.3.################################# [100%]
```

then I start the server

```
 systemctl start mysqld
```

After this I try to access the server with no password for root. I get error as:

```
[root@host1 mysql]# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

As I have not set any password, not very sure why this error comes. After this I tried various options and mone could help me.

option 1 : asks to make a file and change password by using an init file. I tried using that and got output as:

```
    [root@host1 mysql]# mysqld_safe --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init & [1]28469
    -bash: mysqld_safe: command not found
```

Option 2 : set the password using mysqladmin command

```
[root@host1 mysql]# /usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Option 3 : using mysql_secure_installation

```
[root@host1 mysql]#  mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for root user:
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Option 4 : mysql -u root

```
[root@host1 mysql]# mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

and various others. Can you please suggest what can be issue behind this.

Comment: What operating system. Oops rhel

Comment: mysql -u root  ( don't use the "-p")  ?

Comment: the same: [root@host1 mysql]# mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For those ever in a pickle over this:

1. Stop MySql server
2. Create a text file `onetime.sql` that contains something like:

`set password for 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password789');`

Path that file so it is safe and other users can't get to it, perhaps `/home/jason`

3. Start MySql server with `--init-file` option:

`mysqld_safe --init-file=/home/jason/onetime.sql &`

4. Wait happily while password is changed. Wait won't be long.
5. delete that file ... `rm /home/jason/onetime.sql`
6. Stop MySql server
7. Start MySql server normal way

**Edit** this may be necessary :

Once MySQL has stopped,

edit your /etc/my.cnf file to add the line

```
skip-grant-tables
```

restart it

Connect to MySQL using the root user.

```
mysql -u root
```

Once logged in, you should see the following prompt:

```
mysql>
```

Enter the following commands:

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD("YOUR NEW PASSWORD HERE") WHERE User='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit
```

Now stop MySQL again:

## service mysqld stop

If you edited your /etc/my.cnf file, delete the skip-grant-tables line.

Now restart MySQL and test your new login.

## service mysqld restart

## mysql -u root -p

Comment: thanks for your comment, but I tried this and that's my first option. I got error as "mysqld_safe : command not found"

Comment: `find / -name mysqld_safe`

Comment: It's not in your path

Comment: Ya I tried to find that earlier, no such file in whole system. Am I missing something while installation.

Comment: I was googling around trying to find a conf setting but am on an Android kinda limited. Will keep looking

Comment: edit your /etc/my.cnf file to add the line "skip-grant-tables" did the thing. Thanks a lot

Comment: Seems that was not end of things, now i'm into the database, but when I run command **UPDATE user SET `password`=PASSWORD("root") where User='root';**  I get error as _ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'_

Comment: Did u do `use mysql` ?  You need to get in that special db first

Comment: yes I did. I'm able to see columns of table user by _select * from user_. Also I dont see any column in the table user named password. Strange?

Comment: Sorry check this out you are close https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html

Comment: Set password=password("fffff")

Answer (score 11):

“MySQL v 5.7 or higher generates a temporary random password after installation and stored that in mysql error log file, located at

> /var/log/mysqld.log

for an installation by the MySQL Yum repository on CentOS 6/7.
use below command to see the password:

```
cat /var/log/mysqld.log |grep "temporary password"
```

Comment: perfect solution. I was using rhel7 and mysql 5.7.

Comment: the temp password didnt work for me.  Got the temp password and I used it and it says sorry try again

Answer (score 5):

Just do it:

```
cat /var/log/mysqld.log |grep "temporary password"
```

[Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: dI&2-&FteI8a

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
Securing the MySQL server deployment. Enter password for user root: > type here temporary password
The existing password for the user account root has expired. Please set a new password.
New password: > type here your new password  
Re-enter new password:
```

credits to user .pss

Comment: This was the response that led me to solution.  The others were only partial solutions.

Comment: This solution worked for me too for finding the default root password set by the MySQL NDB Cluster 7.6.7.

Answer (score -1):

For those getting an error that column password doesn't exist do the following:

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD("YOUR NEW PASSWORD HERE") WHERE User='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit
```