# Reset MySQL(Mysql Version:mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.26,) Root Password

Tags: mysql

How to reset Mysql (Mysql Version:mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.26, for linux-glibc2.5 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper)root password..? i have follow the bellow procedure but it's not working. Can you any one please suggest me how to change the password.

Steps:

1. `/etc/init.d/mysql stop`
2. `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`
3. `mysql -u root`
4. Setup new MySQL root user password use mysql;

   ```
   update user set assword=PASSWORD("NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD") where User='root';  
   flush privileges;  
   quit
   ```
5. Stop MySQL Server: `/etc/init.d/mysql stop`
6. Start MySQL server and test it: `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: what about it didn't work

Comment: I wrote this up, not so splendid of a write-up http://stackoverflow.com/a/13480374/1816093  and another one http://stackoverflow.com/a/31394469/1816093 don't think I have 3 or 4 in me

Comment: what error are you getting? maybe you are using ``assword`` rather than ``password`` ?

Comment: After change the password, run mysql with sudo, I mean `sudo mysql -u root -p`. I have been the same issue in Debian 9.4.