# mysql 5.7.9 El Capitan lost password

Tags: mysql

Please help, I've searched all over the internet but nothing seems to be working.

I installed mysql 5.7.9 from the install disk image and received the pop-up with a root password.

I promptly lost the pop-up and therefore the password! Since then I have tried several tutorials but each one doesn't seem to be explicitly for El Capitan.

How can I reset the root password?

So far, I've managed to get to

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

Please help.

Comment: Have you gandered at this [Manual Page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) ?

Comment: or [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31394469) I wrote, the 2nd half of it, after the word **Edit:**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initial authorization issue in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394169/initial-authorization-issue-in-mysql)