# OS X El Capitan: MySQL errors always keep. There's no use to solve it

Tags: mysql, macos, root, osx-elcapitan

Before, I have researched many questions related to my problem at Stackoverflow, but none of these questions answers solved my problems. The following questions:

1. [Initial authorization issue in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31394169/1637530)
2. [MySQL: How to fix access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'?](https://superuser.com/q/603026)

I followed the tutorial: [Installing Apache, PHP, and MySQL on Mac OS X El Capitan](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2015/10/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-el-capitan/)

Follow the terminal:

```
Gustavo-Maci:mysql gus$ export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
Gustavo-Mac:mysql gus$ mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Gustavo-Mac:mysql gus$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Gustavo-Mac:mysql gus$ set password for 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('kartuli')
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
Gustavo-Mac:mysql gus$
```

I use OS X El Capitan 10.11 on a Mac mini with HDs of OSes Phoenix and Windows 10.

Update

I followed the [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90TGTG_4CQ0), but I got an error:

```
Gustavo-Mac:~ gus$ export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
Gustavo-Mac:~ gus$ mysql -u root ;
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem! I followed the @eli's answer at the question [MySQL user DB does not have password columns - Installing MySQL on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30692812/1637530). Only that I had to use sudo to stop and start mysqld and after I followed these commands. The updated tutorial for El Capitan and later users:

Stop MySQL Server:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

Start the server in safe mode with privilege bypass:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

Open a new terminal window:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root;

UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('your password') WHERE User='root';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Exit the `mysqld`:

```
\q
```

Then stop the MySQL Server again:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

Start and export `mysql`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
```

To get new strong password to replace your new password for installing MySQL:

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

Start the MySQL Server:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

If you want to install phpMyAdmin, firstly use git and after you need to sudo for extracting the compacted archive to the restricted folder:

```
cd /Library/WebServer/Documents/; sudo curl -O https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.6.3/phpMyAdmin-4.6.3-all-languages.zip
sudo mv phpMyAdmin-4.6.3-all-languages/ phpmyadmin
cd phpmyadmin
sudo mv config.sample.inc.php config.inc.php
```

Enter http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ and use the user and the password that you have done during `mysql_secure_installation`.

Voilà. ;-)