# mysql_secure_installation problem: access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, installation, lamp, access-denied

I am using fresh installed Ubuntu 19.10 and trying to install LAMP, so I ran the following:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

After that, I had to configure mysql by running the command:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Only to get the following message:

> Securing the MySQL server deployment.
>
> Enter password for user root:
>
> Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I've tried several solutions from Stack Overflow and other websites, but none worked for me.

Tried creating a .sql file setting a password to use it with --init-file and also tried skip-grant-tables as suggested here:
[Initial authorization issue in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394169/initial-authorization-issue-in-mysql). No results.

Furthermore, there is no /var/log/mysqld.log only /var/log/mysql/error.log so I also tried what JGlass suggested here: [Setting root password in fresh mysql 5.7 installation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127537/setting-root-password-in-fresh-mysql-5-7-installation). No results also.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same exact problem and then realized that to login as root in mysql I had to run the command as root:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: thanks a million, it worked! and sucks to mysql for not better describing this behaviour

Comment: was setting up LAMP on a new machine, and hit this. Spot on solution, although when using sudo, you don't seem to need any user or  password at all `sudo mysql`  will also do the job

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the MySQL as root?
If no, try run the `mysql_secure_installation` without `sudo`.

If you was install the MySQL as root in terminal(in my case), I solved this issue using like this `sudo mysql_secure_installation`.

Answer (score 0):

try `rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql` before reinstall `mysql`;

or `rm -rf /opt/homebrew/var/mysql` if in macos with `homebrew`;